# Circuit analysis for RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

I have this circuit and want to calculate the voltage at v2 when t>0. v1 has a 6 volt step at t=0. I tried to do nodal analysis and came to 2 equations for the 2 unknown nodes, but did not know what to do from there. In order to solve this could I simply use v+(v0-v)*e^(-t/RC), with R being the two resistors in series?

[image: schematic diagram]

Comment: Taking the easy way, I think most would compute the current in the series system as a function of time. With that, the voltage drops across each resistor as a function of time becomes trivial. If you instead want to solve this as a simultaneous solution of two equations using nodal analysis, you have two more approaches. The first would be to lay out the nodal equations and then combine them to be based only on the voltage of C vs time. The other would be to do the formal homogeneous and steady state simultaneous solutions for the two unknown node voltages. So what do you want to do?

Comment: I think for now I will continue with the nodal analysis method, I am just confused how to base it only on voltage of C over time.For example, I get a parameter C*d/dt(e1-v2), and I do not know how to simplify that. (e1 is the unknown)

Comment: I've seen the other answers. I'll give it a different shot to see if it clicks with you. Here, I'll treat this by strictly applying straight-forward nodal analysis on the two unknown nodes and move forward from there towards a solution. That solution will not directly answer your question at the outset, but it will show you that the capacitor's voltage is where you wind up if you follow that approach fairly blindly. From there, it's pretty easy to go the rest of the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schematic is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnjgpq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Before I get into the nodal analysis, it might help to know that the capacitor, \$C\$, will have a current in it that follows the equation: \$I_\text{C}=C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}\$.

Using nodal analysis, outflowing currents on the left and inflowing currents on the right, I get these two simultaneous equations from the two unknown nodes, \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}V_1}{\text{d}t}&=\frac{V_0}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}V_2}{\text{d}t}\\\\
\frac{V_2}{R_2}+C\frac{\text{d}V_2}{\text{d}t}&=C\frac{\text{d}V_1}{\text{d}t}
\end{align*}$$

It's very convenient at this point to define \$V_\text{C}=V_1-V_2\$. The following will show why. I'm placing the first equation on the left side and the second equation on the right side, as I develop them further here:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}V_1}{\text{d}t}&=\frac{V_0}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}V_2}{\text{d}t}
\quad& \quad
\frac{V_2}{R_2}+C\frac{\text{d}V_2}{\text{d}t}&=C\frac{\text{d}V_1}{\text{d}t}\\\\
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}\left(V_1-V_2\right)}{\text{d}t}&=\frac{V_0}{R_1}
\quad& \quad \frac{V_2}{R_2}&=C\frac{\text{d}\left(V_1-V_2\right)}{\text{d}t}\\\\
\frac{V_1}{R_1}+C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}&=\frac{V_0}{R_1}
\quad& \quad \frac{V_2}{R_2}&=C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}\\\\
V_1+R_1 C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}&=V_0
\quad& \quad V_2-R_2 C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}&=0
\end{align*}$$

Now subtract the right equation from the left:

$$\begin{align*}
V_1+R_1 C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}-V_2+R_2 C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}&=V_0\\\\
\left(V_1-V_2\right)+R_1 C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}+R_2 C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}&=V_0\\\\
V_\text{C}+\left(R_1+R_2\right) C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}&=V_0
\end{align*}$$

Which in standard form would look like:

$$\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}+\frac{1}{\left(R_1+R_2\right) C} V_\text{C}=\frac{V_0}{\left(R_1+R_2\right) C}$$

(You might also notice that the values of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ have been added, as you might expect to see happen in a series circuit like this. Nothing shocking about that fact.)

I think you can see how to solve that. It's just a first order linear ordinary diff-eq that can be solved in a variety of well-known ways.

---

To keep this a little simpler, set \$\tau=\left(R_1+R_2\right) C\$. Then for example, use the integrating factor method setting \$P_t=\frac{1}{\tau}\$ and \$Q_t=\frac{V_0}{\tau}\$. The integrating factor is then \$\mu=e^{\int P_t \:\text{d}t}=e^\frac{t}{\tau}\$ and the solution is:

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{C}&=\frac{1}{\mu}\int \mu \:Q_t\:\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\mu}\frac{V_0}{\tau}\int \mu \:\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\mu}\frac{V_0}{\tau}\bigg[\tau \mu + A_0\bigg]\\\\
&=V_0 + \frac{1}{\mu}\frac{V_0}{\tau}A_0
\end{align*}$$

To meet the initial condition (assumed) of \$V_\text{C}=0\:\text{V}\$ at \$t=0\$, (when \$\mu=1\$), it must be the case that the constant of integration is \$A_0=-\tau\$.

So the final result of all this is:

$$\begin{align*}
V_\text{C}&=V_0 - \frac{1}{\mu} V_0=V_0\left(1-e^\frac{-t}{\tau}\right)
\end{align*}$$

---

At this point, you still haven't arrived at an answer to your question. The above does not solve for \$V_2\$ as a function of time. It winds up solving the capacitor's voltage as a function of time. However, that is useful to know and you can use that solution to compute the current as a function of time. Knowing the current as a function of time, you've got the voltage drop of \$R_2\$ as a trivial output.

$$I_\text{C}=C\frac{\text{d}V_\text{C}}{\text{d}t}=C\left[\frac{V_0}{\tau}e^\frac{-t}{\tau}\right]=\frac{V_0}{R_1+R_2}\cdot e^\frac{-t}{\tau}$$

Therefore:

$$V_2=R_2\cdot I_\text{C}=V_0\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\cdot e^\frac{-t}{\tau}$$

The voltage divider factor stands out like a sore-thumb here.

---

The simple approach would have been to treat this as a simple RC decay, where \$R=R_1+R_2\$. You wouldn't work as hard, that way. But then, it only gets you one answer rather than learning how to fish for answers, I suppose.

Or you could simultaneously solve the initial pairs of equations; either through substitution and solution or else by sorting out the homogeneous and steady state solutions.

I suppose it depends on what you feel like, at the time?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the right approach:
solve for current first from that you can get voltage.

combining the the two resistors simplifies this a bit.

Answer (score 0):

For a step input (or step change) to a 1st order system, you can always use the the following expression to determine the unknown quantity, \$\small f(t)\$, say:
$$\small f(t)=final\:value + (initial\:value-final\:value)\times e^{-t/\tau}$$

where \$\small f(t)\$ is the voltage, current, charge ... etc to be determined, and \$\small \tau\$ is the effective time constant.

In this case:
$$\small v_2(t)=v_2(\infty)+[v_2(0)-v_2(\infty)]. e^{-t/\tau}$$

where: \$\small v_2(0)=\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}6\$ (assuming the capacitor has zero initial charge); \$\small v_2(\infty)=0\$, and \$\small \tau= (R_1+R_2)C\$.

Comment: how come v2(0) =6? Initially v1 is 0 and then its a 6 volt step.

Comment: By definition, the step is applied at \$\small t=0\$. It's zero at \$\small t=0^-\$.

Comment: Actually v2(0) is not 6, I've corrected answer.

Comment: I see, so would a graph for v2 be one which is decaying?

Comment: Yes, both the current and voltages across the resistors decay exponentially. And the capacitor voltage rises exponentially to 6V.